# Linux Ubuntu, no response from default gateway

Tags: linux, ubuntu, networking, wireless-networking, internet-connection

I have a wireless router with WPA. I manage to connect to the network, but I have no connectivity to the Internet and when I ping the default gateway, I do not get a reply.

I also have access to an unsecured wireless router and when I connect to that, I have connectivity to the Internet.

Furthermore, when I connect from Windows 8 ( I have dual boot ) I have connectivity.

What is the problem and how can I fix it ?

Comment: Check IP address on Ubuntu after connecting. `ifconfig` of `ip addr` in console or in network manager (dont know exactly where)

Comment: The address and the default gateway are set. What do you mean by check ?

Comment: Are you using DHCP?

Comment: Yes. I am using DHCP. The configuration of ip, mask and default gateway is automatic.

Comment: Let's start with some basics... What version of Ubuntu? What is listed  in the file /etc/resolv.conf?

Comment: It's. Ubuntu 12.04. resolv.conf has nothing to do with it. I have pinged 8.8.8.8 and it is not working. I have pinged the default gateway address and it is not working.